# Infinite scrolling using css3 transition working in webkit but not gecko

Tags: css

I am using this CSS3 to create a simple horizontal news ticker:

```
transition: right 13s linear 0ms
```

This works great in webkit, however in firefox it works great for 13s and then stops.

Why does webkit continue the scrolling infinitely, but gecko doesn't?

Edit: here is a standalone example

http://alexcrooks.me/others/newstest/

**Edit: This is now fixed, see my answer below. Thanks to anyone that did take a look anyway.**

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `0ms` value as it's the delay, which is already 0 by default.

`13s` is the duration, so it obviously will stop after 13 seconds. It shouldn't reapeat forever! To understand why it does on webkit, i need some more details (full code, browser and version you're testing it on).

You need an [animation](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp). Here's a little example:

```
@-webkit-keyframes scroller { /* webkit */
    0% {
        left: 0;
    }
    100% {
        left:-100%; /* adjust it to your needs */
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes scroller { /* gecko */
    0% {left: 0;}
    100% {left:-100%;}
}
@-ms-keyframes scroller { /* IE10 */
    0% {left: 0;}
    100% {left:-100%;}
}
@keyframes scroller { /* W3C and future browsers */
    0% {left: 0;}
    100% {left:-100%;}
}

.yourElementClass {
    -webkit-animation-name: scroller;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 13s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; /* set loop */
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate; /* read below */
    -moz-animation-name: scroller;
    -moz-animation-duration: 13s;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;   
    -moz-animation-direction: alternate;       
    -ms-animation-name: scroller;
    -ms-animation-duration: 13s;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;    
    -ms-animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-name: scroller;
    animation-duration: 13s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;    
    animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

I've declared each property individually for clarity purposes, but you can also use the shorthand syntax `animation:scroller 13s linear infinite alternate;` (with vendor prefixes obviously).

Now, something about `animation-direction`. If you set it to `alternate`, after the animation ends it will run *backwards*, so that it generates a nice smooth effect.

If it's not what you want, don't set it ( `animation:scroller 13s linear infinite;` ) and it will take its default value: `normal`. After 13 seconds, it will just start from the beginning.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! Perhaps I should have linked you to the plugin I am using for my news ticker it might have helped. After spending even more time looking at it, I think what the plugin is doing is setting the transition duration back to 0 when it detects the transition has ended, then to 13 again to restart it. This is working in webkit but not gecko!

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=zYu0emSz

Comment: Oh well, it changes everything :) let me look at it

Comment: Sure, I've stripped out everything else and left with a standalone example:

http://alexcrooks.me/others/newstest/

Comment: Looks nice :) anyway, it stopped on my FF too, without giving any console error. Sorry, but you'll have to wait for some JavaScript expert's help...

Answer (score 0):

OK I fixed the issue. The changes I made are:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    eltape.css({"webkitTransitionDuration":dur+'s', "mozTransitionDuration":dur+'s', "oTransitionDuration":dur+'s', "transitionDuration":dur+'s'});
    eltape.css({right:0+'px'});
}, 1);
```

(changed the timeout ms to 1 instead of 0)

```
widths['seg'+$(this).attr('seg')] += $(this).outerWidth(true);
widths.total += $(this).outerWidth(true);
```

(added TRUE to outerWidth so it looks at margin as well as padding)

All working great now!

http://alexcrooks.me/others/newstest/